# Regex with word not in range

Tags: regex

I'm struggling with a regex case
engine: net core 5

Example test:

```
50y old guy living a 5th avenue with weight 50,5kg
```

I would like to split this in a "description" and a "weight group"

My expectation would be that the next regex should get a general description group (greedy) and that the ? (also greedy) quantifier would pick up the weight

```
(?<Description>[A-Za-z0-9 ×,\.-]*)((?<weight>([0-9,.]+)(?<weightUnit>kg|G)))?.*?(?<heartbeat>([0-9,.]*))bpm
```

But I'm missing something as the description group takes the complete text and doesn't seem to exclude the weight and heartbeat (or those aren't filtered out).

In addition; I use the ? parameter after the weight as there are strings where the weight is present and there are strings where the weight isn't present and there are still groups behind (the heartbeat for example which has the same issue). Making the first description group lazy (*?) solves the heartbeat problem but not the weight issue. Probably due the none or one "?" character which is needed as the group isn't always there

https://regex101.com/r/NHaMXi/1

Comment: You can make all these optional (weight and heartbeat) but also need to match the gap in between, something [like this (demo)](https://regex101.com/r/UyFP21/1). Also there seems a bit too much grouping here. Sidenote: You expect input with weight < kg?

Comment: So, `bpm` is always present and weight is not?

Comment: I've looked at the feedback of @bobble-bubble and this seems to helpt. Adding the ^and $ elements seemed to "force" the greediness in place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a negative look ahead `(?![0-9,.]+(kg|G)|[0-9,.]*bpm)` to the `description` match to prevent it consuming weight or bpm:

```
(?<Description>((?![0-9,.]+(kg|G)|[0-9,.]*bpm)[A-Za-z0-9 ×,.-])*)((?<weight>[0-9,.]+)(?<weightUnit>kg|G))?.*?(?<heartbeat>[0-9,.]*)bpm
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/1g8tNzHSvOVHfm).

Some unnecessary escapes and brackets also cleaned up.

---

Side note: The symbol for gram is `g` not `G`, but I left that as is in case your input is expected to contain  `G`.

Comment: Thanks. I've used the negative lookahead also but appareantly missed something there. The feedback from bobblebubble above is also correct where had added in his demo the ^and $ elements forcing the greedinesss in the correct level

with regards to the g and G. I'm aware, but the text is need to parse doesn't follow said conventions